# Odoo V10 - Active records

Tags: python, odoo

I want to retrieve the active records in a function.

Here is my code:

```
def no_duplicate_school_dates(self):
    if self.school_registration or self.school_end_date:
        print "Je commence ma fonction"
        # Récupérer les enregistrement actifs
        records = self.env['ecole.partner.school'].search([])
        for rec in records:
            if rec.school_registration and rec.school_end_date:
                if (self.school_registration >= rec.school_registration and self.school_registration <= rec.school_end_date)\
                        or (self.school_end_date >= rec.school_registration and self.school_end_date <= rec.school_end_date) :
                    print "doublon trouvé"
                    # raise ValidationError("Erreur : La plage de date en chevauche une autre")
                else:
                    print "Pas de doublon trouvé"
```

What should I put on this line?

```
records = self.env['ecole.partner.school'].search([])
```

Thanks you

EDIT : In my model "ecole.partner.school", I have a relation fields.

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    scholarship_ids = fields.One2many(string='School card', comodel_name='ecole.partner.school',
                                      inverse_name='partner_id')
```

I would like the records to be linked to the same partner. A partner can be registered several times in a school at different dates. And I'm trying to recover only the records of the same partner. I will put more information in my question

Comment: What do you mean by "active records"? If you want all existing records in database then you're ok with that line

Comment: Yes currently it is for all recordings. I would like the records to be linked to the same partner. A partner can be registered several times in a school at different dates. And I'm trying to recover only the records of the same partner. I will put more information in my question

Comment: I have solved my problem. I use records = self.env['ecole.partner.school'].search([('partner_id', '=', self.partner_id.id)])